# Update clients after updating Firestore collection name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection that I need to rename.
To do that I'll have to do two things. One, rename the collection, two, update my app (only web right now) to use the new collection name.

My problem is that if I just go ahead and do that, any user that has not refreshed the app won't be able to find the renamed collection.

So, my question is: Is there any best practice to handle this scenario?

I can think of a couple of options:

1. Somehow forcing a reload of the web apps immediately after renaming the collection.
2. Set a feature flag so that the web apps enter into maintenance mode while I update everything and then reload the web apps once the change is finished. Unfortunately the currently deployed web app doesn't have a maintenance mode to enable so this doesn't seem to be a valid solution.

However, I'd like to hear about other options. There might be some best practice that I'm missing. Moreover, I'm aware this is a problem that might be more general than just related to Firestore. For example when changing a REST API endpoint, so I guess there must be some tried and tested solutions out there.

I tried searching for best practices regarding this and couldn't find any.
Also, if I was consuming a REST API it would be easier to solve because I could change the DB and keep the DB unchanged. But given that Firestore gets consumed directly from the web app I don't have this benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Locking out outdated clients is a common practice, but leads to a lesser user experience. It also requires that you have a mechanism for the clients to detect that they're outdated, which you don't seem to have.

The most common practice I know of is to perform dual writes to both the old and the new collection while clients are updating.